# How do you make Greasemonkey Click a link that has specified text?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click, greasemonkey

Alright basically i want to click a link that changes but always has the same text name.
Heres an example of what the code might be

```
<a href="unlock.php?confirm=MD5hashere">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a starter script that does that.  Note that it uses jQuery and assumes you are running Firefox or using Tampermonkey, if you are on Chrome.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

//--- Note that the contains() text is case-sensitive.
var TargetLink = $("a:contains('Click Here')")

if (TargetLink.length)
    window.location.href = TargetLink[0].href
```

See also:

- [Adding keylistener and using javascript to click a link in Greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288420/adding-keylistener-and-using-javascript-to-click-a-link-in-greasemonkey)
- ["Normal" button-clicking approaches are not working in Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511381/normal-button-clicking-approaches-are-not-working-in-greasemonkey-script)
- [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS version using XPath:

```
document.evaluate("//a[text()='Click Here']", document).iterateNext().click()
```