# How to have greasemonkey Check if text if found on page

Tags: text, greasemonkey

I did do some research on google and the userscripts site but was unsuccessful in finding an answer.

So basically how can I check if specific text is found on a page?
And the text is in no special tags or anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A crude but fast way, for FF GM:

```
if (/Text you are looking for/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
{
    alert ("Found it!");
}

//--- Looking for one of two different texts...
if (/(Text ONE that you are looking for)|(Text TWO that you are looking for)/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
{
    alert ("Found one!");
}
```

For more focused searches use [jQuery `contains`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=contains-selector) as in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036737/how-do-you-make-greasemonkey-click-a-link-that-has-specified-text/5036877#5036877).

Comment: `innerHTML` works with Chrome, so that code should work.  I only mentioned it because some people get spun up about innerHTML because *writing* to it is problematic on IE.  Here we are just scanning it, anyway.

Comment: @Rayz321, Re: `"Also what would i do if i wanted to search for more than 1 different thing?"`     --- Updated answer to show that concept.

Answer (score 4):

for example this script will show if the text `specific text` is found on this page.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           so5059986
// @namespace      test
// @description    test
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059986/how-to-have-greasemonkey-check-if-text-if-found-on-page
// ==/UserScript==

var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'specific text')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var node=xpathResult.singleNodeValue;
if (node==null)
    alert("text not found");
else
    alert("text found on page");
```

I don't know what you mean with special tags. Text is always inside some tags.

Comment: I just ment that it was in normal tags and im testing it now

Comment: Im trying to get it to work to just alert if there is text and it wont seem to work Go ahead and look on http://jsfiddle.net/tQFLz/2/ to see

Comment: @Rayz321:  There was a syntax error `if (node == null) {};` and the jsFiddle options were not correct for that kind of code.  Replace `{};` with `noop;`  or just go to http://jsfiddle.net/tQFLz/4/ -- but prepare to be annoyed every 3 seconds. ;)

Comment: Maybe its just me but it seems to alert even when i remove the text? Oh never mind i got it lol

Comment: Also what would i do if i wanted to search for more than 1 different thing?