# How do I make Greasemonkey click a link that has specific Text?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

So far I have this,

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Random Creature LevelUP for Avadopts
// @namespace      Xaric
// @description    Clicks randomcreature for leveling up on Avadopts
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @include *


//--- Note that the contains() text is case-sensitive.
var TargetLink          = $("a:contains('Give a random creature a level!')")

if (TargetLink  &&  TargetLink.length) 
     window.location.href    = TargetLink[0].href
```

But it doesn't work.

Any thoughts to get it working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make Greasemonkey Click a link that has specified text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036737/how-do-you-make-greasemonkey-click-a-link-that-has-specified-text)

Answer (score 1):

The [metadata section](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) must be formatted precisely.

### That section is *still* malformed.

Use:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Random Creature LevelUP for Avadopts
// @description     Clicks randomcreature for leveling up on Avadopts
// @include         http://avadopts.com/*
// @include         http://www.avadopts.com/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Note that the contains() text is case-sensitive.
var TargetLink              = $("a:contains('Give a random creature a level!')");

if (TargetLink  &&  TargetLink.length)
    window.location.href    = TargetLink[0].href;
```

Comment: Link to the page in question, or paste its source-code at pastebin.com, and link to that.  This code works perfectly on a page that has such a link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9tH7vSeF @Brock Adams here is the pastebin of the source code.

Comment: Xaric, I see that you've updated the question code. Good.  Now notice that the question code ignores the problems pointed out in the answer!!  I gave you a complete working script, it doesn't get any better than that. ... Tested on that site... Works as designed.

Comment: No, you had a malformed metadata block. Everything from `// ==UserScript==` to 
`// ==/UserScript==` has very specific rules.

Comment: I also noticed that I forgot to add in semicolons. that could be possibly the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a 'contains' css pseudo class but you can always just loop through the links.

```
var l = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var i = l.length; 
while (i--) {
    if (l[i].innerHTML == "Give a random creature a level!") {
        window.location.href = l[i].href;
        break;
    }
}
```

For more reliable results you could use a regular expression:

```
var l = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var i = l.length; 
while (i--) {
    if (l[i].innerHTML.match(/random creature/)) {
        window.location.href = l[i].href;
        break;
    }
}
```