# "Normal" button-clicking approaches are not working in Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey

Here is the button on the page:

```
<a id="dispatchOnJobButton" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Dispatch on next job</span>
</span>
</a>
```

I need Greasemonkey to click it.  I tried many different methods, but none seem to fire whatever function it is supposed to run.

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
clickEvent.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.getElementById('dispatchOnJobButton').dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

// also tried
document.getElementById('dispatchOnJobButton').click();
// and this
unsafeWindow.document.getElementById('dispatchOnJobButton').click();
```

any ideas on something else I could try?

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to do this before the DOM is loaded? Did you try putting it inside a window.onload = function(){} clause?

Comment: Can you find out how the event is attached to the element? try to call it directly

Comment: It's definitely running after the DOM is loaded, no question.  So far I can't locate the event attached to it, and figured clicking the link was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not every button works off a click event.  Also, it's not clear if this is a statically loaded button, or if it's loaded by AJAX. (Link to the target page!)

A general approach is given in [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site).

Something like this **complete script** will work in 99% of the cases:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("#dispatchOnJobButton", triggerMostButtons);

function triggerMostButtons (jNode) {
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "click");
}

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, **Link to the target page, or post [an SSCCE!](http://sscce.org/)**

Comment: I wish I could link to the target page for you, but it's on a private network.  I'll give your code a try.

Comment: Wow, it finally works.  I just needed all the other events apparently.  Thanks Brock