# How to get some code to run on just `.html` webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have some code which I'd like to run on `mywebsite.com/x.html`
(where `x` could be anything).

This code below (I'm hoping) will find the button on the webpage with the ID 'mybutton' and automatically click on it after a delay of 1 second:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
      setTimeout('document.getElementById('mybutton').click()', 1000);
  }
</script>
```

I Googled and found the Tampermonkey Chrome extension but the only problem is that I have no idea how to run it only on the specific webpage(s) mentioned above.

I kinda just slapped my code onto the end of the example layout given by Tampermonkey and got this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        http://website.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
      setTimeout('document.getElementById('mybutton').click()', 1000);
  }
</script>
```

How can I make it run on the specific webpages mentioned at the beginning?

Comment: Start by removing those `<script>` tags from the script file.

Comment: `if (window.location.pathname == "x.html")` should do.

Comment: Set the [@match pattern](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. To **restrict operation to just `.html` pages**, either check the `location.pathname` (see below)
   or use `@include`.  EG:

   ```
   // @include http://website.com/*.html
   ```

   For precision and performance, I recommend using `@match` more than `@include`.
2. You almost always **need a wildcard** at the end of the `@match` directive. EG:

   ```
   // @match http://website.com/*
   ```

   Note that wildcards are much more flexible in `@include`s, but they are "safer" and perform faster in `@match`s.
3. You **can't put direct HTML tags**, like that `<script>`, in a userscript.  Anyway, it is not needed at all in this case.
4. You rarely need `window.onload` in a userscript.  **Userscripts fire at an ideal time by default, for most cases.**
5. **Do not use "eval" strings** in `setTimeout`.  This has performance, troubleshooting, and security problems -- if it works at all.
   The question's `setTimeout` use has most of those, and a syntax error as well.
6. A straight `.click()` call will sometimes work, and [many times not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511381/normal-button-clicking-approaches-are-not-working-in-greasemonkey-script).
   If it doesn't work, **send [a click event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512019/331508).**
7. **Avoid arbitrary timers.** EG:  `setTimeout(..., 1000);`
   This is a form of "Time bomb" code.  It will work sometimes. Other times, the page will be delayed.  When it works, it may slow your script down far more than is necessary.
   **Use [an AJAX aware utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).**  See the code below.

---

Putting it all together, using jQuery and a standard utility to both save work and increase robustness, your script would be something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Auto click the X button on Y pages
// @match    http://website.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

//--- Does the *path* part of the URL end in `.html`?
if (/\.html$/i.test (location.pathname) ) {
    waitForKeyElements ("#mybuttonID", clicktargetButton);

    function clicktargetButton (jNode) {
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define what web pages the Tampermonkey code will run on using an asterisk as a wild card.
So this makes it work on any subdirectory of your website:

```
// @match   http://www.mywebsite.com/*
```

To make it just work with html pages, change up the wild card:

```
// @match   http://www.mywebsite.com/*.html
```

Comment: Where would I insert this?

Comment: Does not restrict it to just `.html` pages.

Comment: Then just change up the way the wild card works,

I'll make an edit to show how.

Answer (score 0):

you can get current url segments via pure javascript with this code:

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```

so if your link is mywebsite.com/about, about will be url[1]

you can define pages array where you want to execute your code and then check with current url

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var pages = ['home', 'about', 'services'];

for(var i=0; i<pages.length; i++) {
    if(pages[i] === url[1]) {
        // execute your code
    }
}
```

Comment: The code will still run on all pages (and all domains) - it just won't do much on most of them.